# Bloquear botão até a function ser completada AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Estou precisando de uma maneira de bloquear um botão até que a função do 
`ng-click` seja completada, para evitar que o usuário clique novamente no botão, pensando que não aconteceu nada ou algo do tipo.

Existe alguma boa maneira de se fazer isso, usando diretivas ao algo do tipo?

Comment: Sempre tente postar o que fez junto para não ter downvotes

Comment: certo, me desculpe.

Comment: +1 a pergunta é boa e a explicação dispensa a colocação de códigos.

Comment: Retiro o que eu disse, após ver o seu questionamento. Você deveria ter colocado essa informação na pergunta antes de o AR responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isto:

```
<button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="isProcessing">Save</button>


$scope.save = function(){
  $scope.isProcessing = true;
  $http.post('localhost', data).success(
    $scope.isProcessing = false;
  );
}
```

Comment: Então, eu havia pensado nesta possibilidade só que como são muitos botões para alterar, estava tentando achar uma solução mais pratica, não sei se existe uma diretiva ou algo assim que possa me ajudar.

Comment: @Brayan é só aplicar a mesma lógica atribuindo a um objeto ligado a um botão. A resposta não precisa necessariamente fazer pra você. Ele já te mostrou o caminho ;)

Comment: Entendi, irei fazer desta forma então, Obrigado :D

Comment: @Brayan se estiver usando o `ng-repeat`, você pode fazer usando o objeto do `ng-repeat` (eu sempre faço assim)

Answer (score 2):

Como complemento à resposta do Otto, sugiro você usar `finally` ao invés de `then`, pois, se ocorrer uma falha, a variável que indica carregamento ficará travada "para sempre".

Eu faria assim:

```
<button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="isProcessing">Save</button>


$scope.save = function(){
  $scope.isProcessing = true;
  $http.post('localhost', data)
  .finally(function () {
      $scope.isProcessing = false;
  })
 .then(function (response) {
      $scope.resposta = response.data;
  })
}
```

O `finally` é executado sempre ao final da requisição, independente de ter terminado com falha ou não.